# 3d bar chart with dataframe in pivot table format

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a csv with data like the below, which I have had to convert to a pivot table to normalise the data, and ensure that response times where a server does not have a value is filled with the integer 0

```
                   ||Count
    ============================================================
    ResponseTime   ||  Server1 || Server2 || Server3 || Server4  
    1              ||   2488   ||  168    ||  33845  || 465             
    2              ||   962    ||  56     ||  0      || 397        
    3              ||   1062   ||  362    ||  55398  || 123        
    5              ||   3876   ||  0      ||  41236  || 359        
    33             ||   9345   ||  562    ||  28731  || 456        
    45             ||   0      ||  412    ||  78945  || 369        
    90             ||   623    ||  365    ||  58963  || 0
```

I am now attempting to draw a 3d bar chart with this information in matplotlib, but I am having issues being able to unravel the pivot data, and see the count as something that could be seen as values of the z axis.

If i print the columns contained in my dataframe I receive the following:

```
    > print(df)
    [('Count', 'Server1'),
    ('Count', 'Server2'),
    ('Count', 'Server3'),
    ('Count', 'Server4')]
```

Can someone help me to put this together?

Comment: To clarify what you'd like to draw:
You want x-axis (or y-) server number, y-axis (or x-) response time, and then bars for counts?
Have you considered what will happen if your view angle has a tall bar instead of a short bar?

Comment: Hey James, yeah working with x as the response time, and y as the server number. Worrying about a tall bar shouldn't be too much of an issue, as I was hoping that I could change the viewing angle.

Comment: Ok eboni, can you `print(df.columns.names`)?